# Python plotly animated scatter plot, show all colours on the legend

Tags: python, plotly, legend, plotly-python

[image: DataFrame]
[image: Graph Input]
[image: Graph Output 1]
[image: Graph Output 2]

Hi all,

I have a plotly animated chart where the colour of the chart changes based on a discreet value in the "Vol" column. However the legend on the left only shows one colour on the chart how can I change this so that the legend has all the chart colours

Thanks!

Best,

MS

I tried adding Highest Vol to the color keyword and I was expecting a legend on the left with all the different highest vol values.

Here is the graph code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig2 =px.scatter(df3,\
        x="Curve", y="Curve Level", 
animation_frame="Date",color="Highest Vol",\
        hover_name="Curve Level",title="Monthly Evolution of US 
Yield Curve (2006 - 2023)",\
        text="Curve Level",range_y=[0,6],
        size="Vol Level", size_max=20)
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
Date    Curve   Curve Level Vol Level   Year    Yc  Curve Steepness Max Rate    Max Rate Name   Max Vol Highest Vol Size
2166    2022-12 30Y 3.66    3.035295    2022    Inverted    -0.67   4.71    6M  4.110371    3M  0
2167    2023-01 1M  4.52    4.273428    2023    Inverted    -0.68   4.80    6M  4.273428    1M  1
```

In this example, 1M should be displayed in orange just below 3M in blue.

Comment: can you please provide the input data and the code with the error message ?

Comment: There's no error message, I am just trying to get all the colours of the chart animation onto the legend, not just the original colour.